# How to Represent a Person Who is not a User in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns

I'm trying to build a rails app similar to a CRM, where I have users, and each use has many "clients".

Initially, I created a model for a user and one for client, but while writing unit tests I realized these two are very much the same.

So my question is: was my original design decision to model them separately correct? Or is there a better way of reusing the code, even though I don't foresee Clients ever being able to actually log into the system?

I've looked at similar questions but they all apply to different user types and roles. In this case, Clients only exist as a model and will never actually BE users.

Comment: What about having a column called `is_client`?

Comment: need to look at the attributes of users and clients, in general a user who can log in has attributes like password, last login etc. If clients are not actual users then it makes sense to keep them in a separate model.

Comment: I'm not a fan but this may be a case where STI plays a part?

Comment: @tihom: I agree. I think I was trying to be too DRY.

Comment: A good option to consider is studying OpenERP (an open source extensible business platform) and how it handles users and customers, maybe this will give you some insights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any CRM application, User and Client there are similarities and differences between them. Let's put some details

**The Similarities**

- Both of Users and Clients share various attributes, especially those related to personal information (name, contact info, ...etc.)
- Both (mostly) represent one and only one person who has a relation to the system. One obvious exception are system users.

**The Differences**

- A user accesses the system. This implies security needs such as authentication, identification and authorization, which in turn implies some validation (passwords, certificates, ...etc)
- In CRM, a Client usually has various relationships such as with Account, Company, Team, Account Manager, and others, a User doesn't. Even though this is not handled by the model, but you might choose to do some model-level validations on some fields

Therefore, the choice of separating Users and Clients in two different models, combining them, or subclassing from a parent is a choice based on your actual need. There are some systems (such as [OpenERP](https://www.openerp.com/), if I remember correctly) treat Client and User in the same manner, while defining an `is_system_user` property. Personally I'd choose to separate them for the differences mentioned and for security reasons. If you're not sure about your need, it's safer (while not DRY'er) to separate them.

Comment: I was thinking the same. There's a bit of code that's being duplicated in having two classes, but that probably makes sense given that, as you say, there are far more differences than similarities. I think trying to be super DRY in this case is overkill.

Comment: You can always maintain DRY'ness by subclassing from a parent that maintains commonalities. You might temporarily choose to sacrifice it when your specific need is still not clear. This is a common practice in agile development disciplines

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should give a type to users (by creating a Type model and making a has_many/belongs_to ActiveRecord association for example): so a user can be a client or anything else you want.

Then, you can manage user permissions with [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) (a very great gem), depending of their type.